# How to setup WCF service to run on HTTPs

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, https

I have created a wcf service, and want to run on secure way(https)

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>    
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>    
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration ="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress = "http://localhost:8734/Service1/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>

        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1">

          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>            
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">             
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>             
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I have tried to change the base address from `http` to `https`.
And I have created self sign certificate from IIS and bind it with https with port `8374`

Comment: Please have a look on this msdn link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556232(v=vs.110).aspx.
you need to perform multiple steps to make it work.

Comment: where the link?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556232(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try with that configuration. I have changed the binding from BasicHttpBinding to BasicHttpsBinding and added "serviceCredentials" section where you have to select your certificate from some store on your machine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>    
    <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" />
    </system.web>    
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="WcfServiceLibrary1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
                <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpsBinding" contract="WcfServiceLibrary1.IService1"/>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
                    <serviceCredentials>
                        <serviceCertificate findValue="" storeLocation="LocalMachine" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" storeName="My"/>
                    </serviceCredentials>             
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>             
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <protocolMapping>
            <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
        </protocolMapping>    
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

P.S. If the web service is hosted in IIS then you don't need baseAddress and port. Port Binding is done from the IIS Manager